# physical significance of latent variables in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, latent-variable

Just curious to know the meaning contained in the latent variables used in the machine learning applications ?

Basically, I am confused if latent variables present the same essence as the model parameters ? In [Parameters vs latent variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139066/parameters-vs-latent-variables), @alberto suggested that parameters are fixed while latent variables are essentially random variables that are not observed directly.

My point is that even a parameter is a random variable (its just that we do not know the value of this parameter). Surely, we know the distribution that it is coming from and using this distribution as a prior information, we try to estimate the value that fits the training data well. Am I going well with this concept ?

Comment: Parameters are constant across all data points while latent variables can vary. Yes, parameters can be treated as random variables too, which was pointed out in the other thread.

Comment: @shimao I've copied your comment as an answer. If you would prefer to write your own answer, please let me know and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are constant across all data points while latent variables can vary. Yes, parameters can be treated as random variables too, which was pointed out in the other thread.

---

I've copied @shimao's comment as an answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

- [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
- [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)
- [We have a very large & widening gap between questions and answers. How do we fix it?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix)